# How to prevent update a pretrained model if a model is optimized with backpropagation?

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation, optimization

These are components in my model:

- A generator
- An encoder: a pretrained, and should not updated.
- A loss function.

Input is passed to the encoder to generate X, X is then passed to generator to generated a value Y. Y is passed to the encoder to get Z. The loss function computes error between Z and X. I detached X to prevent update the encoder. But I cannot detach Z, otherwise, the generator cannot be updated. But I also realize if Z is not detached then the encoder is also updated.
In the case, how can I prevent the encoder being updated, and still allow the generator get feedback from the loss?

Comment: It depends on the framework you use

Comment: I used pytorch, and could you explain how it depends on the framework?

Comment: according to the rules of this community, programming questions are not allowed, so you better ask your question on StackOverflow. but there are a couple of ways to achieve it. You can disable backpropagation for specific layers or you can call `loss.backward()` to calc the gradients and `optimizer.step()` to update the weights for a specific part of your model

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze a model's parameters in pytorch using the following code:

```
for param in encoder_model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

or you can simply not pass the encoder's parameters to the optimizer

```
optim = optim.Adam(generator_model.parameters())
```